# How to indent custom uilabel in a UITableViewCell when editing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a custom uitableviewcell that i would like to indent when I turn on this:

`[self.boatsDisplay setEditing:YES animated:YES];`

Could anyone provide me a hint or some guidance?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `-layoutSubviews`. When the cell's editing bit is set to YES, `-layoutSubviews` will automatically be invoked. Any changes made within `-layoutSubviews` are automatically animated.

Consider this example

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGFloat xPosition = 20.0f; // Default text position

    if (self.editing)
        xPosition = 40.0f;

    CGRect textLabelFrame = self.textLabel.frame;
    textLabelFrame.origin.x = xPosition;
    self.textLabel.frame = textLabelFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `UITableViewDelegate` you can use the `tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if(tableView.editing == YES){
    return 1; // or higher integer
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

if you want to check for your custom cell only you can add `&&[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] isKindOfClass:yourTableViewCell]` in the if condition.